# Drupal 7 user registration: creating mandatory gender/city fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, user-registration

I'm a Drupal newbie, but have successfully installed it at a CentOS 5.5 Linux, PostgreSQL 8.4.7, PHP 5.3 machine.

I've chosen minimal installation and then enabled following modules: Block, Image, Locale, OpenID (hope to add Google accounts later...) and Search. The User module etc. are enabled by default anyway.

My problem is:

I don't know how to add Gender/City fields and make them mandatory.

As a SPAM-fighting measure at [my old phpBB 3 site](http://preferans.de) I have a mandatory question for new users about their gender: **Robot/Male/Female** and the first answer is default and prevents the new user from registering.

Is it possible to do the same in Drupal 7?

And I hope it is doable without installing any additional modules as the stock install is easier to update. (That is what I was doing with my old phpBB site - with no mods installed).

Thank you for your answers! Alex

**UPDATE:**

Here is my Field module screenshot, does it look ok?
Maybe my problem is that List is shown as **disabled**?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that there is a huge difference between Drupal modules and phpBB mods. Drupal provides API's which allows modules to integrate with Drupal without changing any code. You can just download them into a folder, enable and they are running.

And yes, what you are trying to do is possible without any additional modules. Just go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields, add a Gender field of Type "List (text)" (If that is not available, you might need to enable it, but it part of Drupal core), then, enter the allowed values and on the second page, check the "required" and "shown on registration form" checkboxes and you are good to go.

Comment: Under Home » Administration » Configuration » People I do not see "Fields", do I need to activate some module maybe?

Comment: Field UI module, if you haven't that already. Also note that it's called "Manage fields".

Comment: Hi Berdir, do you maybe mean Drupal 6? I don't see "Fields" or "Manage fields" in my Drupal 7 under Home » Administration » Configuration » People. Also I've updated my question by adding a screenshot of the "Field" module.

Comment: Oops, now I've found the "Field UI" module and switched it on. I can see "Manage fields" tab now, thanks

Comment: How can you please enable "List (text)", I only have "Text" and similar types there?

Comment: By enabling the List module :)